# React Native - how do calculation in local variable

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native

I am new to react native. I have to modify someone's else code. 
Got a error when compiling the following code, would someone help:

```
class MyCart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      coupon: props.couponCode
    }
  }

  render() {
    var {cartItems, totalPrice, isFetching, discountType} = this.props

    var couponBtn = Languages.Apply
    var colors = [Color.darkOrange, Color.darkYellow, Color.yellow]
    var sPrice = discountType == 'percent' ? totalPrice - this.getExistCoupon() * totalPrice : totalPrice - this.getExistCoupon();
    const finalPrice = sPrice + (sPrice * 0.09);
```

The error is something like "Unterminated regular expression ..."

in the "const finalPrice" line.

THANKS

---

Here is getExistCoupon:

```
getExistCoupon = () => {
let {couponCode, couponAmount, discountType} = this.props;
if (couponCode == this.state.coupon) {
  if (discountType == 'percent') {
    return couponAmount / 100.0
  }
  return couponAmount
} else {
  return 0
}
```

}

Comment: What's in `this.getExistCoupon()`?

Comment: Rey, I added the getExistCoupon. Thanks for your time.